# Perl IDE over SSH

Tags: linux, perl, ssh

is there a Perl IDE / Editor that supports working on files remotely (via SSH)?

Currently I'm using the shell with vim & nano on the remote machine, and when working locally, I usually use Aptana Studio (Eclipse + EPIC).

p.s: I'm working under linux.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could mount the remote file system with sshfs then work on it with any local IDE

Comment: Good Idea, will give it a try and come back to post. +1

Comment: You would then be using the local perl interpreter, which is fine as long as you remember to test the script on the host computer (or indeed wherever it is going to run). To combat this issue a similar solution would be to tunnel X over ssh (ie. `ssh -X my.host.name.com`) and use the IDE from the host AND its perl interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Active State's [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) for the last few years. It's free, cross platform (linux, OSX, windows), can edit over scp or sftp and works well with perl. Active State also make the non-free Komodo IDE that is a more full featured IDE.

Komodo can also do vi emulation, which was a trifecta for me (perl/ssh/vi).

Answer (score 2):

It's not an IDE in the click and drool sense, but Emacs + Tramp is what I use (and these days, Tramp is included with Emacs).

Answer (score 0):

I use [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) via Putty + WinSCP